# Display issue - Android x86 - Lenovo Miix 310

Tags: linux, display, android-x86

I'm trying to install Android x86 on my Lenovo Miix 310. I made a bootable USB, entered setup mode in the device and booted the USB.

I can see the menu on which I can choose from live, live debug, installation, advanced and Windows. The menu is display ing just fine.

I load live just to see if it works. Everything is great, I have picture, sound and Wi-Fi. But while the live was loading, I couldn't see the usual text like "Loading /kernel" etc. but just some dots and hyphens.

Everything looked okay, apart that loading so I tried to install it. Again, while the installation was loading, I couldn't see the usual text like "Loading /kernel" etc. but just some dots and hyphens.
After that "loaded", I could see a blue background and some text, but it was duplicated horizonatally and vertically, it was wrongly orientated etc. I couldn't read anything from it.

I've seen some sites saying how to adjust screen resolution and hardware acceleration by editing a file in debug mode. But guess what happened again - I couldn't see the usual text like but just some dots and hyphens.

More technical data:

- Tablet: Lenovo Miix 310-10ICR
- Tablet storage: 32GB eMMC
- Tablet screen resolution: 1280 x 800
- Tablet operating systems: Windows 10 x64, Phoenix OS (I want to remove both and only keep Android x86)
- Installation media: 16GB 2.0 USB
- Installation software: UNetbootin
- Android x86 version: "android-x86_64-8.1-rc2.iso" (latest)

Any idea would be really appriciated.

P.S. I tried installing Phoenix OS and there were no issues, but I don't like the launcher and the ads...

EDIT: I (think that I) can confirm that the issue is the screen resolution. Later into booting live, the display fixes, but that doesn't happen when installing. A driver issue?

EDIT 2: I tried using an online tutorial as a reference to install as I can barely see something, but like five seconds in the installation and then the screen turns blank.

EDIT 3: Seems like a known issue with newer BIOS: https://www.bios-mods.com/forum/Thread-REQUEST-Unlock-BIOS-for-Miix-310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, the BIOS was the issue. Flashing "1HCN30WW" as stated here: https://www.bios-mods.com/forum/Thread-REQUEST-Unlock-BIOS-for-Miix-310 fixed the display.

Just be sure to enable BIOS back flash in BIOS to be able to install the old one.

Also, if you get a blank/black sreen at some part, use "nomodeset" as stated here: http://www.android-x86.org/documents/how-to-boot-the-android-x86-live-cd-when-you-have-problems-with-your-graphiccard.

Regards.